# Pricing initialization in SOline dac

Tags: acumatica

I am looking for the best possibility to initialize the tarifs.
using the fielddefaulting event, the amount stays at 0

```
protected void SOLine_CuryUnitPrice_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
  
  var row = (SOLine)e.Row;
  SOOrder order = (SOOrder) Base.Document.Current;
  BAccount un_compte=PXSelect<BAccount , Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>.Select(this.Base,row.CustomerID);
  if (row.InventoryID!=null)      
  {
     InventoryItem un_article=PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(this.Base,row.InventoryID);
    
      string taxe=Convert.ToString(order.TaxCalcMode);
      if ((un_compte!=null) && (un_article!=null))
      {
          if ((un_compte.GetExtension<BAccountExt>().Usrcattarifaireclient=="cat1") && (taxe=="N"))
          {
            decimal? tmp=un_article.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>().Usrprxht1;
            e.NewValue=tmp;
          }
          if ((un_compte.GetExtension<BAccountExt>().Usrcattarifaireclient=="cat1") && (taxe=="G"))
          {
            decimal? tmp=un_article.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>().Usrprxttc1;
            e.NewValue=tmp;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: FieldDefaulting executes when inserting new records. Remove conditions and try a more simple assignation to debug whether or not the value is initialized, ex: e.NewValue = constant. After that you can use a field updated event to check if another process is updating the value after initialization.

Comment: It is possible CuryUnitPrice is updated based on UnitPrice field with PXDBCurrency attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the event : SOLine_UOM_FieldUpdated.
Everything works perfectly, including the webservices

```
    protected void SOLine_UOM_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
      
      var row = (SOLine)e.Row;
      row.CuryUnitPrice=tmp;
    }
```